# Is it permissible to say that specific individuals are among the dwellers of hell?

Tags: halal-haram, jahannam, kuffar

Is it permissible to say that a specific non-Muslim individual is in
hell fire?  Or say a specific individual Muslim is in jannah?

And is it possible for there to exist different views between Allah's judgement and shari'a judgement about someone?  E.g. someone could be non-Muslim in shari'a but a Muslim by Allah's judgement.

Answer (score 2):

You must believe this with certainty about Abu Lahab, Abu Jahl, and Iblis since there are explicit texts about them.

Otherwise, you can have legal rulings that someone is a kafir or mushrik and therefore in the hellfire forever, but since their fate is not adjudged based on what the texts say about them but by rulings made by people who are not considered infallible, there's no guarantee that someone adjudged to be a kafir was at heart a kafir. That doesn't give you license to think someone isn't in the hellfire if he was adjudged a kafir, at most you can hope the judge was wrong.